# Managing alpine component outside x-data

Tags: alpine.js

So I am trying to manage the data of an alpine component outside the x-data... for example:

```
<div x-data="toastr()" x-show="isOpen">
    <span x-text="title"></span>
    <span x-text="body"></span>
</div>

<script>
    function toastr() {
        isOpen: false,
        title: '',
        body: '',
        open() {
            this.isOpen = true
        },
        set(data) {
            this.title = data.title
            this.body = data.body
        }
    }
</script>


.... other html

<script>
    toastr().open();
    toastr().set({
        'title': "Hello",
        'body': "Some body",
    });
</script>
```

When I call `toastr()` for open and set, it doesn't show the toaster and I am assuming it doesn't update the title and body too... How can I achieve this?

Comment: you forgot the closing spans inner the div container.

Comment: can you share the console output?

Comment: There's no errors, the div (toastr) just doesn't show.

Comment: Are you using Alpine.js v2 or v3 the answer will vary based on that